# Serialization Code Causes Unhandled Exception

Tags: c#, serialization, autocad, unhandled-exception, autocad-plugin

I am attempting to create a some code that can serialize and deserialize a library of Classes into an AutoCAD drawing. This question has little to do with AutoCAD other than it being the reason why I cannot debug it by normal means. I started this project from [this article](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/05/serialize-a-net-class-into-an-autocad-drawing-database.html) and successfully got his code to run. However the way his code is structured, It would require me to have all of my classes inherit from his baseobject. As this clearly is a code smell, I knew I needed to create an interface instead. Below is the code that I ended up with.

This first section is the code responsible for doing the serialization into an AutoCAD drawing.

The second section is an example of a class that implements my custom serialization interface

```
public class Commands
{
    public class MyUtil
    {

        const int kMaxChunkSize = 127;

        public ResultBuffer StreamToResBuf(MemoryStream ms, string appName)
        {

            ResultBuffer resBuf = new ResultBuffer(new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.ExtendedDataRegAppName, appName));

            for (int i = 0; i < ms.Length; i += kMaxChunkSize)
            {

                int length = (int)Math.Min(ms.Length - i, kMaxChunkSize);

                byte[] datachunk = new byte[length];

                ms.Read(datachunk, 0, length);

                resBuf.Add(new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.ExtendedDataBinaryChunk, datachunk));
            }

            return resBuf;
        }

        public MemoryStream ResBufToStream(ResultBuffer resBuf)
        {

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            TypedValue[] values = resBuf.AsArray();

            // Start from 1 to skip application name

            for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
            {

                byte[] datachunk = (byte[])values[i].Value;

                ms.Write(datachunk, 0, datachunk.Length);

            }

            ms.Position = 0;

            return ms;

        }

        public void NewFromEntity(IClearspanSerializable objectToSave, Entity ent)
        {

            using (ResultBuffer resBuf = ent.GetXDataForApplication("Member"))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                bf.Binder = new MyBinder();

                MemoryStream ms = this.ResBufToStream(resBuf);
                objectToSave.SetObjectData(bf.Deserialize(ms));
            }

        }


        public void SaveToEntity(IClearspanSerializable objectToSave, Entity ent)
        {

            // Make sure application name is registered
            // If we were to save the ResultBuffer to an Xrecord.Data,
            // then we would not need to have a registered application name

            Transaction tr = ent.Database.TransactionManager.TopTransaction;

            RegAppTable regTable = (RegAppTable)tr.GetObject(ent.Database.RegAppTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

            if (!regTable.Has("Member"))
            {
                RegAppTableRecord app = new RegAppTableRecord();

                app.Name = "Member";

                regTable.Add(app);

                tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(app, true);
            }


            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            bf.Serialize(ms, objectToSave);
            ms.Position = 0;

            ent.XData = this.StreamToResBuf(ms, "Member");;


        }
    }

    public sealed class MyBinder : SerializationBinder
    {
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            return Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}, {1}",

              typeName, assemblyName));
        }
    }


    [CommandMethod("SaveClassToEntityXData", CommandFlags.Modal)]
    public void SaveClassToEntityXData(IClearspanSerializable objectToSerialize)
    {

        Database db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;

        PromptEntityResult per = ed.GetEntity("Select entity to save class to:\n");

        if (per.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
            return;

        MyUtil util = new MyUtil();



        // Save it to the document
        using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {

            Entity ent = (Entity)tr.GetObject(per.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

            util.SaveToEntity(objectToSerialize, ent);

            tr.Commit();
        }

        // Write some info about the results

        //ed.WriteMessage("Content of MyClass we serialized:\n {0} \n", mc.ToString());

    }


    [CommandMethod("GetClassFromEntityXData", CommandFlags.Modal)]
    public void GetClassFromEntityXData(IClearspanSerializable objectToRestore)
    {

        Database db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;

        MyUtil util = new MyUtil();

        PromptEntityResult per = ed.GetEntity("Select entity to get class from:\n");

        if (per.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
            return;

        // Get back the class
        using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            Entity ent = (Entity)tr.GetObject(per.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            util.NewFromEntity(objectToRestore, ent);

            tr.Commit();

        }

    }
}
```

Here is a dummy class I am attempting to test with:

```
[Serializable]
public class MattMember: IClearspanSerializable
{
    public string Name;
    List<int> MattsInts;


    public MattMember(string passedName, List<int> passedInts)
    {
        Name = passedName;
        MattsInts = passedInts;
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("Name", Name);
        info.AddValue("MattsInts", MattsInts);
    }

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    public void SetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
        }
        Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));

        MattsInts = (List<int>)info.GetValue("MattsInts", typeof(List<int>));
    }


    void IClearspanSerializable.SetObjectData(object objectInDisguise)
    {


        if (objectInDisguise == null)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
        }

        MattMember objectToCopy = (MattMember)objectInDisguise;

        Name = objectToCopy.Name;

        MattsInts = objectToCopy.MattsInts;
    }
}
```

and here is the interface:

```
public interface IClearspanSerializable
{
    void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context);
    void SetObjectData(object objectInDisguise);
}
```

When I attempt to run the code inside AutoCAD, All I get is this error. Which leads me to believe there is a simple bug in my initialization of my classes. Non of my breakpoints get hit.

[image: Unhandled Exception]

How should I debug this? and where have I screwed up my initialization?

[EDIT]-Here is what is in the "Details":

```
******************************************************************************
Application does not support just-in-time (JIT)
debugging. See the end of this message for details.

************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Object firstArgument, MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Object firstArgument, MethodInfo method)
   at Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.CommandClass.InvokeWorker(MethodInfo mi, Object commandObject, Boolean bLispFunction)
   at Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.CommandClass.InvokeWorkerWithExceptionFilter(MethodInfo mi, Object commandObject, Boolean bLispFunction)
   at Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.PerDocumentCommandClass.Invoke(MethodInfo mi, Boolean bLispFunction)
   at Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.CommandClass.CommandThunk.Invoke()


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Acdbmgd
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AcdbMgd.DLL
----------------------------------------
adui20
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/adui20.DLL
----------------------------------------
AdUiPalettes
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AdUiPalettes.DLL
----------------------------------------
WindowsBase
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/PresentationCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationCore.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xaml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xaml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xaml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
AdApplicationFrame
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 5.2.8.100
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AdApplicationFrame.DLL
----------------------------------------
AdWindows
    Assembly Version: 5.2.10.200
    Win32 Version: 5.2.10.200
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AdWindows.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Classic
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.classic/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.classic.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
accoremgd
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/accoremgd.DLL
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
Acmgd
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/Acmgd.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcWindows
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AcWindows.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcWindows.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcWindows.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcCui
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AcCui.DLL
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemXml
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework.Aero
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework.Aero/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationFramework.Aero.dll
----------------------------------------
WindowsFormsIntegration
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsFormsIntegration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsFormsIntegration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationUI
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationUI/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/PresentationUI.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml.Linq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml.Linq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll
----------------------------------------
FeaturedAppsPlugin
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.46.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/ProgramData/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/Autodesk%20FeaturedApps.bundle/Contents/Windows/2015/Win32/FeaturedAppsPlugin.dll
----------------------------------------
UIAutomationTypes
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/UIAutomationTypes/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/UIAutomationTypes.dll
----------------------------------------
PresentationFramework-SystemCore
    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/PresentationFramework-SystemCore/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/PresentationFramework-SystemCore.dll
----------------------------------------
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/mscorlib/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
AcLayer
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AcLayer.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcLayer.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcLayer.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcAeNet.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcAeNet.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcCloudRender.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcCloudRender.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcCustomize.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcCustomize.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcDxWizard.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcDxWizard.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcExportLayoutUI.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcExportLayoutUI.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcInterfere.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcInterfere.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcLayerTools.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcLayerTools.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcMrUi.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcMrUi.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcMultiLineUi.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcMultiLineUi.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcRecoverAll.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcRecoverAll.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcScaleList.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcScaleList.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcUnderlay.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcUnderlay.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcViewTransitionsUi.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcViewTransitionsUi.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AdskConnectionPointMgd.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AdskConnectionPointMgd.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcCalcUi.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcCalcUi.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcLivePreviewContext
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AcWindows.dll
----------------------------------------
AcDialogToolTips
    Assembly Version: 20.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/AcDialogToolTips.DLL
----------------------------------------
AcDialogToolTips.resources
    Assembly Version: 0.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 20.0.51.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Autodesk/AutoCAD%202015/en-US/AcDialogToolTips.resources.DLL
----------------------------------------
Write To Block
    Assembly Version: 1.0.5276.26438
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Clearspan/AutoCAD%20Projects/Write%20To%20Block/Write%20To%20Block/bin/Debug/Write%20To%20Block.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
Application does not support Windows Forms just-in-time (JIT)
debugging. Contact the application author for more
information.
```

Comment: Please click the details button first and paste the details to the post. I wonder why this question get 5 upvotes.....

Comment: What version/bitness of AutoCAD is this?

Comment: This is AutoCAD 2015 on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its
>   signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the
>   delegate type.

My understanding is that your interface's "GetObjectData" method conflicts with the ISerializable one, somewhere in the BinnaryFormatter kitchen.

Just refactor all the conversion function (StreamToResBuf, ResBufToStream...) in your MyUtil and you should be able to serialize/deserialize *any class* marked with the [Serializable] attribute.
Your dummy class should look like this (collection and primitive types are auto-serialized, implement ISerializable only when needed) :

```
[Serializable]
public class MattMember
{
    public string Name;
    List<int> MattsInts;
}
```

The NewFromEntity method (avoid any unnecessary cast here) :

```
    public object NewFromEntity(Entity ent)
        {    
            using (ResultBuffer resBuf = ent.GetXDataForApplication("Member"))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                bf.Binder = new MyBinder();

                MemoryStream ms = this.ResBufToStream(resBuf);
                return bf.Deserialize(ms);
            }    
        }
```

and finally your command :

```
[CommandMethod("GetClassFromEntityXData", CommandFlags.Modal)]
//Updated return type here but don't know if it is correct with AutoCAD
public object GetClassFromEntityXData()
{
    Database db = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
    Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
    object objectToRestore;

    MyUtil util = new MyUtil();

    PromptEntityResult per = ed.GetEntity("Select entity to get class from:\n");

    if (per.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
        return;

    // Get back the class
    using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        Entity ent = (Entity)tr.GetObject(per.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead);
        //Cast to your IClearspan interface here, or use Reflection
        // to determine deserialized object's Type
        objectToRestore = util.NewFromEntity(ent);

        tr.Commit();
    }

    return objectToRestore;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Object firstArgument, MethodInfo method, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
   at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type type, Object firstArgument, MethodInfo method)
   at Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.CommandClass.InvokeWorker(MethodInfo mi, Object commandObject, Boolean bLispFunction)
```

It is important to interpret the stack trace correctly.  None of the code you posted is involved, it never got started.  This failed when AutoCAD tried to call your command handler:

```
[CommandMethod("GetClassFromEntityXData", CommandFlags.Modal)]
public void GetClassFromEntityXData(IClearspanSerializable objectToRestore)
// etc..
```

AutoCAD is not going to give you that *objectToRestore* argument, it doesn't know beans about your interface.  Which is what the exception means, it cannot bind a delegate to a method with a mystery argument.  Note how the example code you started from uses a method without arguments.  And how it used Editor.GetEntity() to allow the user to pick a drawing entity.  I assume you need a similar scheme, I don't know enough about AutoCAD scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark: You need either a default constructor since someone else constucts your object:

```
public MattMember()
{

}
```

or a special deseralization-constructor like this:

```
    protected MattMember(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
// Set object data    
    }
```

Probably your interface also need to inherit from ISerializable

Answer (score 0):

```
[CommandMethod("SaveClassToEntityXData", CommandFlags.Modal)]
public void SaveClassToEntityXData(IClearspanSerializable objectToSerialize)
```

> The function that implements the command cannot accept parameters, but inside the command implementation you can accept parameters using command line input functions like GetString(), GetInteger(), etc. that can be found under the Editor class.

From http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/07/create-command-with-parameters.html